# MongoDB SUM Of 2 Columns

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a following documents in my collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5785e5649b732ab238cfc519"), "name" : "Apple", "category" : "Fruit", "price" : 100, "discount" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5785e5709b732ab238cfc51a"), "name" : "Orange", "category" : "Fruit", "price" : 90, "discount" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5785e5819b732ab238cfc51b"), "name" : "PineApple", "category" : "Fruit", "price" : 60, "discount" : 2 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5785e5969b732ab238cfc51c"), "name" : "Potatto", "category" : "Vegetable", "price" : 10, "discount" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5785e5c39b732ab238cfc51d"), "name" : "Cabbage", "category" : "Vegetable", "price" : 5, "discount" : 1 }
```

**And Expected Result**

```
{ "_id" : { "category" : "Vegetable" }, "total" : 15 }
```

And I am using mongoDB query to find the Sum of total with vegetable category as follows

```
db.stall.aggregate([{$group: {_id: {category: "Vegetable" }, total: {$sum: "$price"}}}]);
```

**But I am getting the following result**

```
{ "_id" : { "category" : "Vegetable" }, "total" : 265 }
```

How should I find the sum of total and discount columns with vegetable category.

Comment: You should consider to show sample document with the expected output not table.

Comment: Yeah sure I will update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I'm getting your question right but this will filter the sume of Price and sum of Discount for Vegetable category.

```
db.stall.aggregate([
   {
      {$match : {category : "Vegetable"}},
      {$group : {_id: "$category", sumOfTotal : {$sum : "$price"}, sumOfDiscount : {$sum : "$discount"}}}
   }
])
```

Comment: Hi Tan, thanks for your answer. I am getting the following error message

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: Thanks Tan It works fine :) group by with missing "_id".